# DROP DATABASE no phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Como faço para habilitar o `DROP DATABASE` no phpmyadmin?

Todas as vezes que tento dropar um banco dá erro dizendo que o comando não está habilitado.

Estou utilizando o phpMyAdmin no WAMP da minha máquina local.

Comment: É um banco local ou de algum servidor externo? Pode ser alguma restrição de permissão do usuário do banco. Vá em [edit] para inserir detalhes mais relevantes.

Answer (score 3):

No phpMyAdmin se não me falha a memória o comando `DROP DATABASE` vem desabilitado por motivos de segurança.

Para ativá-lo é preciso alterar a configuração do phpMyAdmin.

Procure a linha `AllowUserDropDatabase` no arquivo `config.inc.php` na pasta do phpMyAdmin e altere seu valor para `true`.

Feito isso, reinicie os serviços do Wamp e seu MySQL estará ok.

**Referencia:**

http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_AllowUserDropDatabase

Answer (score 1):

**Muito fácil:** Se está no phpMyAdmin vá ao painel de controlo e abra também o MySQL® Databases (onde se criam as bases de dados e os seus utilizadores). Em baixo, em Current Databases, pode ver as base de dados criadas, BASTA SELECCIONAR A BASE DE DADOS QUE DESEJA APAGAR e clicar em REMOVER.